# Use mysqldump to export data that is compatible with older versions

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use a newer version of mysqldump to export data that is compatible with older versions of mysql?

Specifically, I am using mysqldump to export data from version 5.5.44 to  5.1.55.

I was getting the error

> Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

when trying to import data from the 5.5.44 to the 5.1.55 server

I know in the manual, it says that the `compatible` option can be used with one of the following names: `ansi, mysql323, mysql40, postgresql, oracle, mssql, db2, maxdb, no_key_options, no_table_options, or no_field_options`, but I'm not sure if that is what I want in this situation.

Comment: not really sure what your question is... do you want to know if you'll be able to restore it to the same server or a newer one? or if the data will be usable at all

Comment: I guess I should have included this in the question, but I was getting the error `Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` when trying to import data from the 5.5.44 to the 5.1.55 server.

Comment: did you fix the problem?

Comment: I think so. I used the mysql40 compatibility, and that appears to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I really wanted a sure-fire solution I would use mysql40 - 5.1 can definitely load a dump from 4.0, MySQL philosophy is backwards compatibility to a fault. However, it is quite likely to work as is - dumps have not changed very much between 5.1 and 5.5.